# How to query a table in flask?

Tags: flask

A user have logged in and submitted 2 projects. I need to have a list of submitted projects by this user.
In my `models.py` I have a `Project` table:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    users = db.relationship(User)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False) # means users.id is a ForeignKey for user_id

    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow) 
    title = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)  # Project TITLE
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False) # JUST A TEXT OF THE PROJECT

    def __init__ (self,title,text,user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.user_id = user_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Project ID: {self.id} --Date: {self.date} -- {self.title}"
```

This is the route that I use to submit a project:

```
@app.route('/create_project', methods = ['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def create_project():

    form = ProjectForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        print(current_user)
        project = Project(title = form.title.data,
                    text = form.text.data,
                    user_id = current_user.id
                    )

        db.session.add(project)

        db.session.commit
        flash('Project created')

        return redirect(url_for('welcome_user'))

    return render_template('create_project.html', form=form)
```

When I submit a project, the code works well and I have a flash message that project is submitted. This means the data enters into a database.

However when I want to see the projects created by the same user:

```
# User's list of PROJECTS:
@app.route("/<first_name>")
@login_required    # to make sure that user must be logged in to see that view
def user_posts(first_name):

    #requesting a page
    page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
    user = User.query.filter_by(first_name=first_name).first_or_404()

    # filtering the blog posts by username
    projects = Project.query.filter_by(author=user).order_by(Project.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5) # comes from backref='author' on models.py

    return render_template('user_projects.html', projects=projects, user = user)
```

in `user_projects.html` I have the following:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div align="center">
      <h1>Welcome to the page for {{user.first_name}}</h1>

    </div>

  </div>
USER PROJECTS <br>
project ID
<hr>
{{projects}}
<hr>
USER
<hr>
{{user}}
<hr>
  {% for post in projects.items %}
    <h2> <a href="{{url_for('project', project_id=post.id)}}">{{post.title}}</a> </h2>

    <p class="text-muted">Published On: {{post.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}</p>

    <br>
    <p>{{post.text}}</p>
    <br>

  {% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

While I do have a user information inside this template, I can access name, surname etc., I have nothing inside a projects object, however I have `<flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination object at 0x0000024F5E334CD0>` on a screen - meaning that at least the query worked well and there is something in it.

I wonder how can I verify the content of the given table - when I create a test route:

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    test = Project.query.all()

    return render_template('test.html', test=test)
```

I see nothing inside a `test` object. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot the brackets behind the `commit` command within your route to save. The function is therefore not called and the new project is not stored in the database. The table is empty.

```
@app.route('/create_project', methods = ['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def create_project():
    form = ProjectForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        project = Project(
            title = form.title.data,
            text = form.text.data,
            user_id = current_user.id
        )

        db.session.add(project)
        db.session.commit() # <-- The brackets were missing here!
        
        flash('Project created')
        return redirect(url_for('welcome_user'))

    return render_template('create_project.html', form=form)
```

Your queries appear correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like i's extremely tired. It's just I don't understand why it did not show any error - I was absolutely sure everything's fine

Comment: @Lara It didn't throw an error because you asked for the function but didn't execute it. It is possible to query the function and assign it to a variable or transfer it as a callback. It is only called explicitly through the brackets at the end, in which possible arguments are also passed. So the code you wrote was valid and error-free. This just didn't do anything.